# Changing attributes with click and querySelector not fully functioning

Tags: javascript

I've written this to change the background of a `div` that represents hours on a daily planner. The first instance (`onclick`) works but the others don't. Do I need to give each `.container` their own `id` and their own function?

```
var changeStatus = document.querySelector("#changeStatus");
var container = document.querySelector(".container");

changeStatus.addEventListener("click", function () {
  container.setAttribute("class", "filled");
}
```

Comment: `querySelector` returns only the first match, so you are only attaching a listener to one element. You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to return a NodeList of matches which you can then iterate over and attach listeners to each result, or better yet, use [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) to attach a single listener to a common ancestor and handle the `even.target` to affect specific elements.

Comment: the eventlistener has an event parameter. That parameter contains the element that fired the event:  `changeStatus.addEventListener("click", function (event) { 
 event.currentTarget.setAttribute("class", "filled");  }  `

Answer (score 2):

`querySelector()` is designed to return a single element only. If there are multiple elements matching the `.container` selector then it will only return the first.

In your case you need to use `querySelectorAll()` to retrieve all relevant elements, then you need to loop through them to update the `class`.

```
var changeStatus = document.querySelector("#changeStatus");
var container = document.querySelectorAll(".container");

changeStatus.addEventListener("click", function () {
  container.forEach(el => el.setAttribute("class", "filled"));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add click listener with loops, something like this:

```
changeStatus.addEventListener("click", function () {
    for(var i=0; i<container.length; i++) {
        container[0].setAttribute("class", "filled");
    }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with `querySelectorAll` as @pilchard answered above:

```js
var changeStatus = document.querySelector("#changeStatus");
var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");

changeStatus.addEventListener("click", function () {
  containers.forEach(function (container) {
    container.setAttribute("class", "filled");
  });
});
```

```css
.filled {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<button id="changeStatus">change status</button>
<div class="container">container 1</div>
<div class="container">container 2</div>
<div class="container">container 3</div>
```